# Missing image metadata when saving updated image into PhotoKit

Tags: ios, swift3, core-graphics, photosframework

I am having an issue updating an image's metadata and saving that back to the Photos library. Everything *works* except that the image metadata after it's altered has missing entries that were there before and I am not getting any errors manipulating the image or executing the photos library change block. Also, the dictionary before it's written back into the image looks like the original plus my dictionary in the debugger.

My questions are:

1. What am I doing wrong that would cause rewriting the existing
   properties back with additional data to wipe out what is there?
2. Is there better, more canonical way to do this? It seems like a lot of mechanics to update some meta data in an image. It just seems like
   What Everyone Else Is Doing.

**EDIT:**

Before the save all the Exif and Tiff values are present. This is the entirety of the metadata after the save to photos using the code below:

```
["PixelHeight": 2448, "PixelWidth": 3264, "{Exif}": {
ColorSpace = 1;
PixelXDimension = 3264;
PixelYDimension = 2448;}, "Depth": 8, "ProfileName": sRGB IEC61966-2.1, "Orientation": 1, "{TIFF}": {
Orientation = 1;}, "ColorModel": RGB, "{JFIF}": {
DensityUnit = 0;
JFIFVersion =     (
    1,
    0,
    1
);
XDensity = 72;
YDensity = 72;}]
```

The code, all in Swift 3, testing on iOS 10.1

The basic workflow is:

```
    // Get a mutable copy of the existing Exif meta
    let mutableMetaData = getMutableMetadataFrom(imageData: data)

    // Check to see if it has the {GPS} entry, if it does just exit.
    if let _ = mutableMetaData[kCGImagePropertyGPSDictionary as String] {
       callback(imageAsset, true, nil)
       return
    }

    // Add the {GPS} tag to the existing metadata
    let clLocation = media.location!.asCLLocation()
    mutableMetaData[kCGImagePropertyGPSDictionary as String] =
       clLocation.asGPSMetaData()

    // Attach the new metadata to the existing image
    guard let newImageData = attach(metadata: mutableMetaData, toImageData: data) else {
            callback(imageAsset, false, nil)
            return
    }

    let editingOptions = PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions()
    imageAsset.requestContentEditingInput(with: editingOptions) { editingInput, info in
        guard let editingInput = editingInput else { return }
        let library = PHPhotoLibrary.shared()
        let output = PHContentEditingOutput(contentEditingInput: editingInput)
        output.adjustmentData = PHAdjustmentData(formatIdentifier: "Project", formatVersion: "0.1",
                                                 data: "Location Adjustment".data(using: .utf8)!)
        do {
            try newImageData.write(to: output.renderedContentURL, options: [.atomic])
        } catch {
            callback(imageAsset, false, error)
            return
        }

        library.performChanges({
            let changeRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest(for: imageAsset)
            changeRequest.location = clLocation
            changeRequest.contentEditingOutput = output

        }, completionHandler: { success, error in ... ...
```

The helper methods to the workflow are:

```
func attach(metadata: NSDictionary, toImageData imageData:Data) -> Data? {

    guard
        let imageDataProvider = CGDataProvider(data: imageData as CFData),
        let cgImage = CGImage(jpegDataProviderSource: imageDataProvider, decode: nil,
                              shouldInterpolate: true, intent: .defaultIntent),
        let newImageData = CFDataCreateMutable(nil, 0),
        let type = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassMIMEType,
                                                         "image/jpg" as CFString, kUTTypeImage),
        let destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData(newImageData,
                                                           (type.takeRetainedValue()), 1, nil) else {

            return nil
        }

    CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, cgImage, metadata as CFDictionary)
    CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination)

    guard
        let newProvider = CGDataProvider(data: newImageData),
        let newCGImage = CGImage(jpegDataProviderSource: newProvider, decode: nil,
                                 shouldInterpolate: false, intent: .defaultIntent) else {

            return nil
    }

    return UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage(cgImage: newCGImage), 1.0)
}

func getMutableMetadataFrom(imageData data : Data) -> NSMutableDictionary {

    let imageSourceRef = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(data as CFData, nil)
    let currentProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSourceRef!, 0, nil)
    let mutableDict = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: currentProperties!)

    return mutableDict
}
```

Also the `asGPSMetaData` is an extension on `CLLocation` than looks a Swift 3 version of [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/rsattar/b06060df7ea293b398d1)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turns out that it was not the manipulation of the image or metadata with CoreGraphics that was the issue at all, it was a couple of things I overlooked:

1. Constructing a UIImage from data that contains EXIF or GPS data
   removes that data... in fact, it removes **most** of the meta data
   except a core set of JFIF and size data (when using JPEG). It makes sense in retrospect as their internal representation would be just raw data. However, I did not find any explicit statement about metadata in the docs.
2. Given the prior point, the main two ways to get a Data (image with metadata) object into
   the Photos library was either to write it to a temp file
   and read it in with
   `PHAssetChangeRequest::creationRequestForAssetFromImage(atFileURL:)`
   or use `PHAssetCreationRequest::forAsset` to create a creation request
   and then use `PHAssetCreationRequest::addResource(with:data:options:)`
   to add the data as a photo. I chose the latter as it had less moving
   parts.

So I guess all that replaces the nice, succinct `ALAssetsLibrary::writeImage(toSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock:)`.

The final change block for the Photos library ended up being this:

```
    var assetID: String?
    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({ 
        let creationRequest = PHAssetCreationRequest.forAsset()
        creationRequest.addResource(with: .photo, data: imageWithMetaData as Data, options: nil)
        creationRequest.location = clLocation
        assetID = creationRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset?.localIdentifier
    }) { success, error  in ...
```

Comment: Correct - as of today, UIImage does not preserve metadata. The docs will be updated shortly to reflect this.

Comment: Still no possible way for uiimage to preserve metadata?It might sound irrelevant but its not, bare with me. I have a photo app which uses GPUImage, when I use input images such as screenshots taken by the phone, it distorts the image but when use an input image such as a photo taken by phone's cam, it wont distort it, I have noticed screenshots don't preserve metadata but camera pics do, any way to fix it? @Ray Pendergraph

Comment: I'm not sure this is likely to be "fixed" as it's not a bug really. A UIImage is really just the memory representation of an image for iOS (which is not explicitly documented, but not an uncommon separation with UI frameworks) and as such would not carry any metadata with it. This is why you will have to use the asset to get the data. Screen shots have Exif data as well (no GPS data).